# Ajax update is not working in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

i am using primefaces 3.2 when try to update the ajax in two differnt forms is not getting updated. See the below code

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{baen.vareable1}">

   <f:selectItem itemLabel="val1" itemValue=="val1"/>

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="val2" itemValue="val2" />

        <p:ajax update="new" listner="#{bean.val()}" event="onchange"/>

</p:selectOneMenu >
```

Comment: Is "new" which you are trying to update in a different form than the current form?

Answer (score 0):

replace `event="onchange"` with `event="change"` or event better remove it completely (cause its the default event)

Comment: even i used default event that is not a problem.

Comment: they are not nested, right ? no `<h:form>.........<h:form>......</h:form> .....</h:form>`

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that a form validation is blocking the request? Try setting `<p:ajax process="@this" .../>`. 
By default the complete form that the component belongs to is processed. So by setting this attribute to "@this", only the selectOneMenu component is processed. An additional advantage is that the request becomes a little bit lighter, because less information is sent to the server.